# How to add multiple CSS classes to HTML node in Closure template (soy)?

Tags: html, css, templates, google-closure-templates, soy-templates

In a template I need to assign more than one CSS class to a div.

However, when I try something like the following, the Closure compiler seems to wrap only the first class in quotation marks, resulting in the browser ignoring the rest.

```
<div class={foreach $cssClass in $cssClasses}{$cssClass} {/foreach}>...</div>
```

[DOM result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MF3a.png)

I tried wrapping the whole thing in quotation marks (with and without `{literal}`)... didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap class in quotations

```
<div class="{foreach $cssClass in $cssClasses}{$cssClass} {/foreach}">...</div>
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch.

Comment: @IanTaylor The liberal surfer don't mess around!

Comment: Damnit! That worked. The reason why it didn't work before was, because I was storing `class={foreach $cssClass in $cssClasses}{$cssClass} {/foreach}` in a variable and then used this variable in the <div>. Anyway... Thank you!

Comment: Addition (can't edit): This was what I had: `{let $classesString} class="{foreach $cssClass in $cssClasses}{$cssClass} {/foreach}" {/let}` and then <div {$classesString}>